# "NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for "character varying":String" after "rake db:migrate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to add check-ins to micro-posts but I've got an error after rake db:migrate.. What does it mean?

**Error**

```
  $ rake db:migrate --trace
    ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
    ** Execute db:load_config
    ** Execute db:migrate
    rake aborted!
    NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for "character varying":String
```

**add_checkin_to_microposts**

```
 class AddCheckinToMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :microposts, :location, :point, :geographic => true
   end
 end
```

**database.yml**

```
 development:
  adapter: postgresql
  schema_search_path: public, postgis
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: ******** 
  password:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the gem `activerecord-postgis-adapter`, you'd better try to change the database adapter to `postgis` as recommended in their official document:

> https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter

Answer (score 1):

the problem that you are having is that **point** method does not exist in ActiveRecord.

Instantiates a new column for the table. The type parameter is normally one of the migrations native types, which is one of the following: :primary_key, :string, :text, :integer, :float, :decimal, :datetime, :time, :date, :binary, :boolean.

For more info pleas read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column

Hope this helps

Comment: which type can I use for location?

Comment: you want to save latitude and longitude?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/312398/Creating-a-location-aware-website-using-Ruby-on-Ra  actually I m looking from this site for creating location-based app but, something is wrong there.. Maybe you can check it, and  I'll be glad to getting your advices @MZaragoza